# Android- Get first Button in Layout

Tags: android, focus, android-button

I need to get the first `Button` in the layout, in order to request focus dynamically.

Is there any function that allow me to resolve my problem ?

Comment: So the question is about getting the *first* Button, not the requestFocus?

Comment: Exact, I need to get the first `Button` of the layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out about the [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) class.

This should do the trick:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<((ViewGroup) layout).getChildCount() ; i++) {
    if(((ViewGroup) layout).getChildAt(i) instanceof Button) {
        // Here is your first Button!
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : I just added `ViewGroup` casts to my answer, just in case the implicit conversion would raise a ClassCastException.